# Vue.js: passing an object as a prop, then using its properties as attributes in a child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to do this. It seems trivial, but is not working.

In my parent component, I'm instantiating the child EndpointDetailsForm component, and passing it the settingsDetails prop, like this:

```
<EndpointDetailsForm :endpointDetails="modalDetails.content" />
```

Inside the EndpointDetailsForm component, I'm retrieving the endpointDetails object, like this:

```
    props: {
        endpointDetails: {
            type: Object
        }
    }
```

and trying to use its various properties as attributes, like this:

```
<b-form-input id="nameInput"
              type="text"
              v-model="form.name"
              :placeholder="endpointDetails.name">
</b-form-input>
```

When I inspect the EndpointDetailsForm component, it shows me the endpointDetails as a prop, but when I inspect the input above, it tells me that the placeholder is null.

What am I missing?

Comment: you passed the prop with the name `settingsDetails` but in the component you are accesssing it using`endpointDetails`

Comment: Sorry, I copy-pasted the wrong component, fixing now.

Comment: Fixed it in the original post. That wasn't the problem.

Comment: is `modalDetails` fetched asynchronously?

Comment: Not for the purposes of this component.

Answer (score 3):

In your template you have to use kebab-cased attributes. [Vue will convert them](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) to camelCased props:

> HTML attribute names are case-insensitive, so browsers will interpret any uppercase characters as lowercase. That means when you’re using in-DOM templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased (hyphen-delimited) equivalents.

Therefore if your prop is named `endpointDetails`, you should refer to it as an attribute as `endpoint-details`. Therefore:

```html
<EndpointDetailsForm :endpoint-details="modalDetails.content" />
```

Code example:

```js
Vue.component('b-form-input', {
  template: '#b-form-input',
  props: {
    placeholder: String,
  },
});

Vue.component('endpointetailsform', {
  template: '#EndpointDetailsForm',
  props: {
    // Vue converts kebab-case to camelCase.
    endpointDetails: {
      type: Object
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    content: {
      name: 'my placeholder',
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- Use kebab-cased attributes -->
  <endpointetailsform :endpoint-details="content" />
</div>

<template id="EndpointDetailsForm">
  <b-form-input :placeholder="endpointDetails.name"></b-form-input>
</template>

<template id="b-form-input">
  <input :placeholder="placeholder" />
</template>
```

Comment: The change you're suggesting is just passing 
```<EndpointDetailsForm :endpoint-details="modalDetails.content" />```?

I've done that, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Hum then there could be something in `modalDetails`, or even other things in your app code that you do not show in your question.

Comment: Actually-the way I was doing it with camelCase, when I inspected the EndpointDetailsForm, its props had the endpointDetails object, so it was getting it. With kebab-case, its props are empty.

Comment: wow scary… something very strange seems to happen in your project!